# Read QR code text and generate new image

Tags: php, character-encoding, qr-code

I have a QR code image that is generated by an invoice system, but it is not designed. So I'm designing a new invoice using the same data and generating a clean QR code with the same information.

The problem is when I read [online](http://lector-codigos-qr.onlinegratis.tv/qr-reader/) the original QR code, it show this information:

Original Image:

[image]

Raw text:
9d8e095a10000692001-001-000004035289445200000

Raw bytes:

```
42 d3 96 43 86 53 03 93   56 13 13 03 03 03 03 63
93 23 03 03 12 d3 03 03   12 d3 03 03 03 03 03 43
03 33 53 23 83 93 43 43   53 23 03 03 03 03 00 ec
11 ec 11 ec 11 ec 11 ec   11 ec 11 ec
```

Barcode format:
QR_CODE

Parsed Result Type:
TEXT

Parsed Result:
9d8e095a10000692001-001-000004035289445200000

And when I read the new RQ code I just generated containing the same text it show the same result except by the "Raw bytes":

New generated image (ECC: H, Size: 5):

[image]

Raw text:
9d8e095a10000692001-001-000004035289445200000

Raw bytes:

```
40 83 96 43 86 53 03 93   56 11 02 c6 40 1b 98 02
40 5e 6a 00 69 10 54 00   01 02 34 85 bd 32 00 00
ec 11 ec 11
```

Barcode format:
QR_CODE

Parsed Result Type:
TEXT

Parsed Result:
9d8e095a10000692001-001-000004035289445200000

I don't know what means the differences between the "raw byte" and why my new QR code is different to the original one.

Regards

Comment: Does anyone know what are the "raw bytes"? And how can I get the text from they?

Answer (score 1):

you are using a different QR module size format then the original,
see here: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=qr%20code%20module%20size
you can change the module size, but you do not have to

Comment: thank you for the help... is there any way to get the QR module size from the original image?